# regexp выделить слова содержащие символ

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер! Есть строка:
"111111 5555%5555 6666 7777%3456789 65678 5678%789878"
Как одним регэкспом выделить слова с % а вторым без % ?

Comment: язык программирования не имеет значения?

Comment: Разбейте предложение на слова любым подходящим для вас способом, а замет получившийся массив разложите в два по наличию `%` в слове.

Answer (score 3):

Можно выделить и те и другие одним выражением в разных группах захвата:

`/(\S*%\S*)|(\S+)/g`

[Демо на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6MKFCq/2)

```js
var reg = /(\S*%\S*)|(\S+)/g;
var s = '111111 5555%5555 6666 7777%3456789 65678 5678%789878';
var m, res = {'+%': [], '-%': []};
while (m = reg.exec(s)) {
  res[m[1]?'+%':'-%'].push(m[1]||m[2]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну например как-то так:
**[^\s]+**

Comment: Как раз для таких случаев есть более удобный `\S+`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @vp_arth, согласен. Я упустил это из виду. **\S+** зарешает.

Answer (score -2):

1. `![^\s]*\%[^\s]*!si`
2. `![^\%\s]+!si`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.